# How do I post on company Facebook pages without my friends being notified?

Tags: facebook-pages

I want to publish on company Facebook pages without my Facebook followers getting notified each time I make a post. How can I do this?

Comment: Are you the facebook page admin? If so, posts on your company page are not, by default, published to your personal feed.

Answer (score 1):

Per [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/52236/38185) (given to a [very similar question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/52217/38185)), you cannot do this.

Facebook Pages are inherently ***public***, and there is no way to hide your activity on them from other people's casual viewing or Graph Search.