# Will my friends see my comments on some business' wall?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-apps, facebook-privacy, facebook-profile

If I don't want my friends to see my comments on some business/company Facebook page, what I do to make sure they won't?

Same thing about Facebook Groups.

Finally, I think lately some Facebook applications surfaced that provide users using them with information on who visited their profile, viewed picture etc.

Aren't such applications against other people's privacy and against the terms of service of Facebook?

What can I do as user to make sure I will still be able to view profile, photo etc. of another person but he won't know this?

Comment: No facebook is very annoying and advertises your comment through peoples "news feed" on a business wall to all of your friends, there doesn't seem to be a way at the time of writing this to stop it.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook Pages are public, subject to any country and age restrictions set by the Page administrators. There's no way to hide your activity on public Pages administered by others, from casual viewing or from Graph Search.
https://www.facebook.com/help/329858980428740

For Facebook Groups, it depends on how the Group was created:
https://www.facebook.com/about/groups

> Secret: Only members see the group, who's in it, and what members
>   post.
>
> Closed: Anyone can see the group and who's in it. Only members see
>   posts.
>
> Open (public): Anyone can see the group, who's in it, and what members
>   post.

Finally, no users can tell if someone has visited their timeline, either through the web interface or through an app.
https://www.facebook.com/help/205685226136386

Comment: So if I commented on business wall but my friend was not in it, he won't get notification of comment? What if I like and comment on business wall? Will my friend see comment or only if he also liked that business' wall?

Comment: I'm not sure if there are concrete rules about what Facebook's algorithms may or may not promote to you or your friends. This seems to be an area of continual experimentation. It is, after all, in Facebook's interest to promote increased sharing and connectedness, though our interests as users may not be aligned with Facebook's interests.